# Overflow of visible part of input field

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

Is there a way to handle the event when last visible character is typed to `input` field?
On screenshot below, it is the moment of pressing <kbd>o</kbd> key

[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This goes to head:

```
function checkInput(input) {
    var overflowing = input.offsetWidth < input.scrollWidth;
    if( overflowing ) {
        // Do something here
        console.log('text is larger than input');
    }
}
```

This is actual input tag:

```
<input style="width: 50px;" value="" onkeypress="checkInput(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it can be done but it's not just one event.

You have to use monospace font like 'Courier'. Monospace font means each char has same width. When you know how much px goes for each char you can calculate width of string. On every keypress calculate `string.length*char_width` which is width of typed text, and when this width is bigger then width of input you activate event.

Something like this.

```
function whenkeypressed(){
   var char_width=2px;//FOR EXAMPLE
   var input1= document.getElementById('id');
   var inputString=input1.value;
   var x=inputString.length*char_width;
   if(x>input1.width){
    alert(1);
   }
}
<input onkeyup="whenkeypressed()"> <!-- THIS INPUT FONT NEEDS TO BE MONOSPACE -->
```

Use written code more as pseudo code, I am not sure if I wrote it correct.